# Bios - wake by alarm -- what happens if computer is already on?

Tags: wake-up, alarm

There are time I need to remote into my desktop for a couple weeks at time. The problem is, there is some strange error going on where the computer (which I have set to never hibernate, ever) --- will shut itself down maybe one every 1-2 weeks. I've checked the system log and can't figure it out for now, maybe sometime in the future.

I was wondering if setting 'wake by alarm' in the BIOS would fix this issue (instead of trying to remote in, and failing, because it's off).

Could I set a 'wake' command at a certain time right before I get to work each day as a failsafe?

What happens if this BIOS wake alarm goes off and the computer is already on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.  Your computer will stay powered up and nothing will happen.

Have you thought about Wake-on-Lan instead of a BIOS alarm?  That would give you complete access to your computer, regardless of when you had your alarm set for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I saw Wake-on-Lan as well. That seems more useful, but also more complicated to set up, right? I don't have admin rights on the computer in question sadly, but I'll talk to the IT team. It definitely would be more fail-safe than a daily wake-up, though.

Comment: You should be able to enable WOL via the BIOS settings, which you may have access to.  You don't need Windows Administrator access to reach the BIOS settings.  However, your IT team will probably need to open the firewall up to allow you to get the WOL signal from your other computer.  I think forwarding UDP port 9 is the usual way.